# run jar in debug mode from terminal

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

I'm using intellij idea IDE and I'm trying to run my jar file from terminal in debug mode and set breakpoints in a few places in the code.

the command I'm using is: `java -jar myTestApp.jar -file "myfile.txt"  -users myUser -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=127.0.0.1,suspend=n,address=8080`

The problem is that I'm also using commons-cli library, so -Xdebug and -Xrunjdwp parameters are not recognized as Options, and I'm getting:[image]
Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Please assume the writer of the question is not using Java 5 in 2018:

`java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8080,server=y,suspend=n -jar myTestApp.jar -file "myfile.txt" -users myUser`

Btw: in case you use [Java 9 and later](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/index.html): change `address=8080` to `address=*:8080` since localhost is no more the default.

**stop telling people to use `-Xdebug` and `-Xrunjdwp`**

[Xdebug](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2010/09/java-agentlibjdwp-for-attaching.html) was used in Java 5 and below. Since Java 6 there is the `-agentlib` available.
`Xdebug` allows access to the debugger over `Xrunjdwp`.  JIT now starts in a compatibility-mode if you use `Xdebug` and uses a legacy-debugger which slows down your debugging extremely.  People tell then to use `-Djava.compiler=NONE` to disable the compatibility-mode or to add `-Xnoagent` to disable the legacy debugger. Don't do that use `-agentlib`!

Comment: The "Java 9 and later" link is broken.

Comment: Updated the "Java 9 and later"-link to show to the JDK overview, since the oracle page structure changed. Thanks for the hint. @LukeHutchison

Comment: Special thanks for taking effort to mention "stop telling people to use -Xdebug and -Xrunjdwp"

Comment: If I got a dollar every time I visit this page to copy the command...

Comment: "myfile.txt should be "myfile.txt" ?

Answer (score 4):

Java expects only program arguments after specifying the class or jar to run. So simply try putting your JVM options before that:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=127.0.0.1,suspend=n,address=8080 -jar myTestApp.jar -file "myfile.txt" -users myUser
```

Comment: Thasks, that worked ( its not throwing an error) but the execution still doesn't stop at breakpoint. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `suspend=y`, which makes the program halt immediately after initialization and wait for a debugger to connect. Also because you're using IntelliJ you can create a run configuration for an external jar, and start that in debug mode.

Comment: downvoted since this answer affect the performance badly and is deprecated since years. See my answer for an up to date solution.

Comment: I used the exact arguments of the original question, it's not my specific advice.

Comment: @Damarus I understand this. But you are spreading, even if its not on purpose, bad information. I'm sorry but your answer should not have a high ranking because of outdated information.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
java -jar -Xdebug  -agentlib:jdwp="transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5000" core-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: I needed to run this jar on a server and debug the code on my local machine in eclipse as Remote java application. So I used this on the server to start the jar

Comment: So I am trying to run a jar file in another device and test it from my local machine, it should be possible right? If so how does the connection looks like in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

-Xdebug should be moved in front of the -jar parameter. Now Java thinks it's part of your program's arguments.

Comment: Xdebug should not be used anymore since this is a Java 5 argument!