# What's the easier way to debug a Minecraft plugin?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

Every time I have an error with my Minecraft plugin I have to do a lot of broadcast messages before the code lines to detect the error line.

Is there an easier way to debug and fix errors for a Minecraft plugin? (I'm using IntelliJ idk if this may help)

Comment: Please paste in your error log. 
Helpful tip: an error log normally tells you where in your code you have a mistake, like so `YourClass:line23` for example.

Answer (score 1):

How about the normal Java debugger?
2 simple ways are

1. If you start the server with [debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54026722/9866079) than you can create a run config (in IntelliJ) to connect to the debug port
2. Which I personaly recommend is to just run the jar through an intellij run configuration. There is one for jar files. Just dont forget to specify the flags you use when starting it normally.